# Adding arrow keys in X-Mouse Button Control

Tags: button-remapping, mouse-buttons, xmouse

I also want to ask just as an extra thing, how to add a profile for stuff like my taskbar. I've searched the internet to no avail. (For the simulated keys e.g. {CTRL} and {SHIFT})

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the list under the "Enter custom key(s)".  I'll paste it here:

> Modifier tags:
> {CTRL} {RCTRL} {ALT} {RALT} {SHIFT} {RSHIFT} {LWIN} {RWIN} {APPS}
> NOTE: modifier tags can be combined like {CTRL}{ALT} but apply to the NEXT KEY ONLY.
> For example, to send CTRL+a+CTRL+s you should type '{CTRL}A{CTRL}S'.

> Extended key tags:
> {DEL} {INS} {PGUP} {PGDN} {HOME} {END} {RETURN} {ESCAPE} {BACKSPACE}
> {TAB} {PRTSCN} {PAUSE} {SPACE} {CAPSLOCK} {NUMLOCK} {SCROLLLOCK} {BREAK} {CTRLBREAK}

> Direction key tags:        {UP} {DOWN} {LEFT} {RIGHT}

There are more when you open the menu, though.  I just didn't want to fill up this post.